# How much virtual memory is preallocated In DPDK

Tags: linux, dpdk

Say suppose I'm running a DPDK process with following configuration:

8 Numa nodes. There are 4 cores per numa node (ie: 32 physical cores)

I'm selecting only cores of first 4 Numa nodes I,e first 32 cores for fast path processing.

But my 2 NICs are plugged in Numa node 6

I have hugepage of size 1G, And no of hugepages requested is 64G (64G/8 NUMA = 8G per NUMA) And have about 256G of total RAM.

Questions:

1. So by the above config and with Max virtual memory limit set to 512G in DPDK common _base file, will DPDK come up? Because it seems 128 G of virtual memory needs to be allocated per numa node and by reaching 5th node 512 G of virtual memory limit would be hit.
2. Even though all the operating cores are in first 4 Numa nodes, but NICs being in last Numa nodes affect the DPDK?
3. Say suppose there are 16 Numa nodes then should we also increase the virtual memory limit in common_base?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for each NUMA node total virtual memory is set to `128G`. With `1G` hugepage size, number of memory segments per NUMA node would be 128 resulting into 128G of max application data memory.

However, since `RTE_MAX_MEM_MB` is set to `512G`, only 4 NUMA nodes of each `128G` could allocate successfully `(4 x 128G == 512G)`. Hence virtual memory limit will hit causing application to fail. In order to support more number of NUMA nodes either we could decrease total memory to `64G` unless application doesn't need higher memory requirements. By bringing down the memory per node there could be a advantage in terms of availability of contiguous VA memory.

Secondly, in NUMA enabled system, packet buffers and descriptor rings should be accessed from same memory domain where the NIC interface is associated to a particular NUMA node, else you will incur QPI bandwidth accessing the other memory domain and much higher latency causing low data throughputs.

Comment: But since all DPDK fastpath cores are on first 4 Numa nodes why it requires preallocated virtual for last 4 Numa nodes to operate?  I agree there will be performance issue while NICs in Numa node 6 access memory from Numa nodes 1-4 but the operation should be fine right?

Answer (score 0):

summarizing the current layout as

```
 - Assuming x86 for 32 physical cores
    No HT: 32 Threads
    with HT: 64 Threads
 - CPU cores from first 4 NUMA selected 
    No HT: 16 Threads 
    with HT: 32 Threads
 - NIC NUMA is 6
 - from total of 256GB, 1GB huge page selected as kernel CMD line for 64 pages results to
    numa 1: 8GB
    numa 2: 8GB 
    numa 3: 8GB
    numa 4: 8GB 
    numa 5: 8GB 
    numa 6: 8GB 
    numa 7: 8GB 
    numa 8: 8GB
```

```
Q1. Max virtual memory limit set to 512G in DPDK common _base file, will DPDK come up? 
Answer> depending upon eal-args passed this can vary. Without passing any fields for `--socket-mem` or `--socket-limit` all 1GB  huge page are consumed. ie: 8GB per NUMA, which can lead to 64GB physical memory mapped to 64GB virtual address + extra space for Linux process
```

```
Q2. Because it seems 128 G of virtual memory needs to be allocated per numa node and by reaching 5th node 512 G of virtual memory limit would be hit. Even though all the operating cores are in first 4 Numa nodes , but NICs being in last Numa nodes affect the DPDK? 
Answer> creating the mempool/mbuf pool is specific to NUMA. You can do this by invoking `rte_eth_get_socketid (portNumber)` or simialr API to avoid wrong NUMA pitfall.
```

```
Q3. Say suppose there are 16 Numa nodes then should we also increase the virtual memory limit in common_base?
not clear> are you reffering 64bit virtual address space or hugepage per NUMA?
```

[update] based on debug session, the information such as virtual-mem, mmu memory. mmap, legacy-mode, socket-mem, API to create per NUMA socket are been shared.

Comment: I just wanted to know how much virtual memory is allocated per node . Say if I have 8 Numa nodes and 64G physical hugepages so il get 8G physical hugepage per numa node right? What about virtual memory which is preallocated? Does it allocate 128 GB per numa node hence failing to allocate virtual memory for last 4 nodes as 512G virtual memory limit is hit as defined in common_base file?

Comment: the questions you have shared does not reflect the same. Please update the question with the same from the comment. With respect to virtual memory it is sum of map huge page  + process map area. Example `64Gb mmap area + .so mapped + linux __start/stack/and others`. Try using `pmap ` or `/proc/pid/stats` for collecting real information.

Comment: By default won't the DPDK allocate 128G virtual huge page memory per node with 1G hugepage? Due to CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_MB_PER_TYPE being 131072 (128G) . if yes, won't it fail to preallocate virtual memory to last 4 numa nodes , as after allocating to first 4 NUMA nodes the virtual memory limit is hit which is defined by CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_MB. This is irrespective of physical hugepages requested . If all cores performing fast path are in first 4 numa nodes but NIC in last 4 Numa nodes , would dpdk still try to preallocate virtual memory to last 4 numa nodes?

Comment: As per your requirement you have stated you have only 64G as huge page, with dpdk 18.11 or greater based on total hugepages availble mmap is created which are maped to huge page in the process. Since 64g mmap fits under 128G my guess is it should not fail. node I test on has maxium of 96gb only. So Can you try it on your node and check as mentioned is previous comment

Comment: the above is made with the assumption you have modified from `CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_MB_PER_LIST=32768` to `CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_MB_PER_LIST=65356` or `CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_MB_PER_LIST=262144`

Comment: I think you are right , virtual memory is preallocated according to the physical hugepages per node but 128G is max limit given the default macros with 1G hugepages. I hadn't modified anything

Comment: thanks for confirming, if you have the node please test the same. The default value is 32G in dpdk-stable-19.11.3 Also if you find this answers helpful please accept and upvote too.

Comment: But I get these following messages, and my DP application doesn't come up:                         EAL: Could not find space for memseg. Please increase CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEMSEG_PER_TYPE and/or CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_PER_TYPE in configuration.
EAL: Couldn't remap hugepage files into memseg lists
EAL: Cannot init memory.     I have 8 NUMA nodes, fast path cores all are running in first 4 NUMA nodes,2 NICs are plugged into numa node 6, hugepage size is 1G and no of hugepages i,e physical is 64 G hence 8 G hugepage per numa node.

Comment: Why am I getting these error messages? If I increase the  CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_MB to 1024G the isssue will be resolved .

Comment: can you use pastebin or some other means to exactly highlight what is that you change and run?

Comment: In DPDK 's config/common_base I changed the CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_MB from 524288 to 1048576

Comment: I am not sure why you have changed the parameter `CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_MB ` and not `CONFIG_RTE_MAX_MEM_MB_PER_LIST`. Humble request to check `https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/env_abstraction_layer.html`.

Comment: Can you explain why the error messages were popping? Is there anything wrong in the setup?

Comment: I have already shared you the link to go through which explains each parameter. if you still not convinced https://lore.kernel.org/dpdk-dev/CAG8PAapbn2WgDASX2gmkWcnCSycetaOaN85Qt4qwYtuJv9_W-Q@mail.gmail.com/

Comment: I just found out that meseg with page size 1gb and socket Id 4 is not present with 512g limit on RTE_MAX_MB and hence mapping was not possible for that Numa node and hence DPDK app was failing with message 'Cannot init memory'. As soon as I increased to 1024GB or limited max_mb_per_type to 64GB the memseg were available for 1gb with socket Id 4. But I can't understand why is this working this way , even though I require only 8gb of mapping per numa node.

Comment: Try using with socket-mem and socket-limit for numa 4. All the answers to your question are shared in the orginal answer. Through comments explanation and additional questions are getting answered.

Comment: Without --socket-mem you told 64gb virtual address is consumed , it should be accommodated within 512gb right? Why only increasing the limit to 1024gb gives the necessary memsegs for mapping even though only 64gb is required is my question.

Comment: this is yet again new question as the original question is `wanted to know how much virtual memory is allocated per node`. note: `socket-mem` is minimum limit and `socket-limit` is upper bound hence requesting to use the combination correctly. with respect to ` 64gb virtual address is consumed ` your default `.config` only address maximum of 32GB mmap huge page. I am not able to find the corrections for the variables as pointied out in couple of comments. hence please share meeting invite via skype, hangout or zoom.

Comment: Can you send me your email, il send the invite link

Comment: I have the mail account in Gmail with same username

Comment: Awesome, have sent you the link

Comment: checked inbox and spam have not received any

Comment: Isn't it vipinvarghese@gmail.com?